# trim() is not working when we try to access value from appliction.properties using @Value annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am trying to fetch properties values using `@Value` annotation like this

```
@Value(value= "#{applicationProperties['twilio.accountSID'].trim()}")
```

But it's throwing an error.

I have even tried both `$ and #` for accessing the value both are not working.

**TwilioAccountAndAuthDetail.java**

```
@Component
@Validated
@ConstructorBinding
public class TwilioAccountAndAuthDetail {
    
    @NotNull(message = "Account SID can't be null")
    private final String accountSID;

    @NotNull(message = "Auth ID can't be null")
    private final String authId;

    @NotNull(message = "Number can't be null")
    @Pattern(regexp = "^[0-9]+$", message = "PhoneNumber should not contains charater other than 0-9")
    private final String phoneNumber;

    public TwilioAccountAndAuthDetail(@Value(value= "#{applicationProperties['twilio.accountSID'].trim()}") String accountSID,
            @Value("${twilio.authId}") String authId,
            @Value("${twilio.phoneNumber}") String phoneNumber) {
        this.accountSID = accountSID;
        this.authId = authId;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    // getters
}
```

**application.properties**

```
#1. ################       DB DETAILS        ###############################
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://remotemysql.com/q5UV1n69DW?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=q5UV1n
spring.datasource.password=Ur
############################################################################

#2. ##############     LOGGING DETAILS FOR APPLICATION     #################
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
#logging.level.org.hibernate=debug
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
############################################################################

#3.###############       TWILLO DETAILS FOR OTP      #######################
#both below twillo details can't be null                        
twilio.accountSID=AC53bec33      
twilio.authId=7c31ef0e28e    
twilio.phoneNumber=16468634753   
############################################################################

#4.###############     OTP CONFIGURATION DETAILS     #######################
#otp.length can not be null. Please provide no. in b/w 4 to 6
otp.length=4
#otp.expirytime can not be null. Please provide no. in b/w 20 to 300
otp.expiryTime=20
otp.message=Your otp is 
############################################################################
```

**Error**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'smsApplication': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'twilioAccountAndAuthDetail'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'twilioAccountAndAuthDetail' defined in file [C:\Users\ragsingh\Documents\WORK\smsService\bin\main\com\custom\store\sms\otp\twillo\model\TwilioAccountAndAuthDetail.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'applicationProperties' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext' - maybe not public or not valid?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:643) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:130) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:897) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:879) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143) ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) [spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) [spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) [spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at com.custom.store.sms.SmsApplication.main(SmsApplication.java:31) [main/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'twilioAccountAndAuthDetail' defined in file [C:\Users\ragsingh\Documents\WORK\smsService\bin\main\com\custom\store\sms\otp\twillo\model\TwilioAccountAndAuthDetail.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'applicationProperties' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext' - maybe not public or not valid?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:797) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:227) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1356) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1203) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:556) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1307) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1227) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'applicationProperties' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext' - maybe not public or not valid?
    at org.springframework.context.expression.StandardBeanExpressionResolver.evaluate(StandardBeanExpressionResolver.java:169) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.evaluateBeanDefinitionString(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1575) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1251) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1227) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:884) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:788) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    ... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'applicationProperties' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext' - maybe not public or not valid?
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:217) ~[spring-expression-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:104) ~[spring-expression-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:91) ~[spring-expression-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueRef(CompoundExpression.java:55) ~[spring-expression-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:91) ~[spring-expression-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:112) ~[spring-expression-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:272) ~[spring-expression-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.expression.StandardBeanExpressionResolver.evaluate(StandardBeanExpressionResolver.java:166) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    ... 38 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Why mix bean expression and java code? You could move the `.trim()` call to the assignment of `accountSID`. Doing this improves readability imho.

Comment: @Nikolas the reason why I haven't used the trim() inside the constructor I thought that for reading the value of type integer if it will pick whitespace in it then what will happen. But just now I tested it it worked fine for it only there is a problem with the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should work:

```
@Value(value = "#{\"${twilio.accountSID}\".trim()})")
```

Note that `${twilio.accountSID}` stands for a standard value parsing. Wrapping between escaped quotes `\"` makes the value inside `#{ }` understood as a `java.lang.String` and therefore the subsequent call of a Java method `trim()` within the `#{ }` block trims the actual String.

The advantage of wrapping between `\"` over `'` characters is that the expression would work even if the property contains the `'` character itself, such as `twilio.accountSID=AC53b'ec33`.

If the property eventually doesn't exist, you get an IllegalArgumentException, you might want to define a default value (`abc`) as well:

```
@Value(value = "#{\"${twilio.accountSID:abc}\".trim()})")
```

Source: Spring Docs [4. Spring Expression Language (SpEL)](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.3.0-SNAPSHOT/spring-framework-reference/core.html#expressions).

Comment: Fails if value of `twilio.accountSID` contains a `'`

Comment: @Andreas: Thanks for a note! I have edited my answer.

Comment: Changing `'` to `"` just means that it will now fail if value contains a `"`, so that's not any better, just different.

Comment: @Andreas: I have no answer for that. In that case your answer would surely be better. If the value is expected to be alphanumeric, then I'd go for mine one.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using the `@Value` annotation for a **parameter**, do the processing of the value in the *Java code*, not in the annotation *expression*.

```java
public TwilioAccountAndAuthDetail(@Value("${twilio.accountSID}") String accountSID,
                                  @Value("${twilio.authId}") String authId,
                                  @Value("${twilio.phoneNumber}") String phoneNumber) {
    this.accountSID = accountSID.trim(); // <=== Call trim() here
    this.authId = authId;
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
}
```

If the annotation had been on a field, use a setter method or post-processing:

```java
// Before
@Value(value= "#{applicationProperties['twilio.accountSID'].trim()}")
private final String accountSID;
```

```java
// Using setter method
private String accountSID; // not final

@Value("${twilio.accountSID}")
private void setAccountSID(String accountSID) {
    this.accountSID = accountSID.trim(); // <=== Call trim() here
}
```

```java
// Using @PostConstruct (JSR-250)
@Value("${twilio.accountSID}")
private String accountSID; // not final

@PostConstruct
private void init() {
    this.accountSID = this.accountSID.trim(); // <=== Call trim() here
}
```

```java
// Using InitializingBean
public class TwilioAccountAndAuthDetail implements InitializingBean {
    @Value("${twilio.accountSID}")
    private String accountSID; // not final

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() {
        this.accountSID = this.accountSID.trim(); // <=== Call trim() here
    }
}
```

Comment: The field in the cases using `@PostContrstuct` and setter cannot be `final`. Yet, I'd prefer them over `InitializingBean`.

Comment: @Nikolas Oops! Good catch. Thanks.